# Preheader in Email template

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template

when we are sending emails through marketing cloud, we are getting Preheader message including Hyperlink,  Is there any way that we can get rid of Hyperlink in Preview??

Note: Its coming only for outlook but not gmail

Comment: Can you include a screen-grab of what you are seeing and the code?  Here is a good reference point for hiding pre-header text:
https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/tips-for-coding-email-preheaders

Comment: I have inserted preheader text in the preheader field in Marketing Cloud but wanted to ask if I need to add any additional code in my html for this to show up? I know that it doesn't render for all email clients.